# Specifying unsigned attribute when using the Schema Builder Trait in MIgrations?

Tags: yii2

I have to specify a column as unsigned in yii2 migrations .
Example migration code from manual

```
public function up()
{
    $this->createTable('news', [
        'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
        'title' => $this->string()->notNull()
    ]);
}
```

From the research I have done there doesn't seem to be a method to add the unsigned capability in schema builder trait.

But is there some other way I can add unsigned attribute to the column while still making use of the schemaBuilderTrait style methods ?

For instance the `$this->string()` above returns an instance of `yii\db\ColumnSchemaBuilder`, but that doesn't even have a property to set unsigned/signed..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, some things are impossible to write with new migrations syntax.

In this case you can use string concatenation like that:

```
'title' => $this->string()->notNull() . ' UNSIGNED',
```

Alternatively you can use old syntax (backwards compatibility is observed):

```
use yii\db\Schema;

...

'title' => Schema::TYPE_STRING . ' NOT NULL UNSIGNED',
```

**P.S.** You can post issue on official framework repo for this problem.

**Update:** It's already implemented, use `->unsigned()` method. Note that you need to update framework. Thanks *leitasat* for information.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'll use the concatenation approach for.

Comment: Unsigned for `string`? What does that do?

Answer (score 6):

Just in case: they [did it](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-columnschemabuilder.html#unsigned()-detail).

Now you can add `->unsigned()` to your definition.